# Reference field in GridView OnClientClick tag

Tags: asp.net

How do I reference a field in the current row through an ASP.NET GridView onClientClick tag.

The following works, however, I have hard coded the text "barcode" in String.Format

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ItemsScannedGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceItems" 
        CssClass="ScannedBarcodes">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick=<%# String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete barcode {0}?');", "barcode" ) %> />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:ImageField DataAlternateTextField="MATCH" 
                DataAlternateTextFormatString="{0}" DataImageUrlField="MATCH" 
                DataImageUrlFormatString="~/images/icons/{0}.png" HeaderText="Match">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BARCODE" HeaderText="Barcode" 
                SortExpression="BARCODE" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Description" 
                SortExpression="DESCRIPTION" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

`<%# String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete barcode {0}?');", "barcode" ) %> />`

I tried replacing "barcode" with `Eval("barcode")` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" 
        runat="server" 
        CommandName="Delete" 
        Text="Delete" 
        OnClientClick=<%# String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete barcode {0}?');", Eval("BARCODE") ) %> />
```

Comment: In debug I get this, An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'BARCODE'.

Comment: I got it, barcode was not actually beeing selected from the SQL, however, the code above must be legacy code from when it was.